# Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be strictly increasing, continuous, and surjective

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

What we want to show is this: If $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, then $g(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Here is what I have:  For any $y \in g(U)$, there is a $x \in U$ so that $g(x) = y$. Since $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, $x$ is an interior point. There is an open interval $(x-\delta, x + \delta) \subset U$. I am not sure what to do next. I want to say that $(g(x) - r, g(x) + r)\subset U$ and conclude that $g(x)$ is an interior point. Do I say this because that $g$ is onto. Am I on the right track? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation, let us consider the images of the points $x \pm \delta$ under $g$.

From the assumption that $g$ is strictly increasing, we know that $g(x - \delta) < g(x) < g(x + \delta)$.

Hence we may choose $r > 0$ such that $g(x - \delta) < g(x) - r$ and $g(x) + r < g(x + \delta)$.

Now I claim that the interval $(g(x) - r, g(x) + r)$ is contained in $g(U)$, thus proving that $g(U)$ is open.

Can you see why?

Comment: Yeah I do see why. Thank you very much for your help! Stay safe!